# Can I use Unbuffered ECC memory with a non-ECC CPU?

Tags: memory, ecc

I recently purchased the Supermicro X9SCL-F with a Core i5-3350P. I realize that the 3350P does not support ECC, and the motherboard requires unbuffered ECC memory.

I do not need ECC. Will unbuffered ECC memory work at all with the 3350P?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I currently have non-ECC memory and I need to exchange that.

Comment: So that motherboard requires unbuffered ECC.. Are you sure that CPU model is compatible with that motherboard?  If so, then you should be good, right? :)

Comment: It is not officially, but I believe that is due to the i5 not having ECC support. It is indeed the correct socket however.

Comment: Uhh, yeah..  Can it work with ECC RAM, probably depends on the motherboard. Since you're using a board that doesn't list that CPU as compatible, then YMMV regardless of ECC.  So I'm not going to try and answer this.  Good luck. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing the i5-3350P with a Kingston KVR13E9/8HM unbuffered ECC memory module, I can confirm that it does not POST at all, and the same 5 short beeps + 1 long 
beep memory error occurs.

It is now running functionally with a Xeon E3-1220.

Thank you for your input on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, is your server working right now with the i5 processor? Yes or No?

According to your motherboard spec's and the chipset, the i5 CPU is not compatible. Moreover, your mobo supports only ECC memory as you know your CPU doesn't support ECC so it may not work as the recent processors have MC's(memory controller) built into the CPU. This means that the CPU needs to manage the memory. Unbuffered memory requires that the CPU manage all of the chips[image].

Also check the following [Memory configuration guide according to Intel](http://cache-www.intel.com/cd/00/00/46/78/467819_467819.pdf) which clears points that i5 and i7 processors are "not supported" though they are of the same socket. (refer page 5 - Intel® C200 Series Chipset Memory Support). Sometimes the system may still boot but `YMMV regardless of ECC -  techie007`. That's just my opinion.

But there is a reason for you to keep your hopes up as this FAQ answered by SUPERMICRO says it should work - [Check this link](http://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=10712). Let us know if it works out.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly this person at webhostingtalk.com tried an i5 Ivy Bridge processor with non-ECC ram and it worked:  http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1159007

He apparently said it has to NOT be ECC ram, otherwise it won't work with the i5 (or presumably i7).  I am not sure if it specifically has to be ivy bridge.

I might try it with a Sandy Bridge i5 to see if those work, too.  I don't have an Ivy Bridge i5.  I'll report back if it works...